# I'm learning JavaScript. What is wrong with my code for a quiz?

Tags: javascript

```
var numofq = 0;
var score = 0;
var questions = [
    "Which has the highest mountain: Earth or Mars?",
    "What are the small indentations on a golf ball called?",
    "Which city has the largest population?",
    "Which country claims the world's tallest building?",
    "With which device are earthquakes recorded?",
    "Name the Yellow Telly Tubby.",
    "What is 'Tiger' Woods's first name?",
    "What are Alpha Centauri and Sirius?",
    "How many men have walked on the moon: 4, 8, or 12?",
    "What is the only word in English ending in the letters 'mt'?",
    "What is the currency of Switzerland?",
    "Who wrote 'Waiting for Godot?'",
    "What is the business term for assets which can be immediately turned into cash?",
    "Which is the largest planet in the solar system?",
    "True or False? Only one word in English rhymes with 'silver'.",
    "Which instrument did Louis Armstrong play?",
    "What is Triskadekaphobia?",
    "On which street do Bert and Ernie live?",
    "Which mythological figure flew so close to the sun that the wax on his wings began to melt?",
    "What is the green pigment in plants called?"
];


var answers = ["Mars", "dimples", "Tokyo", "Malaysia", "seismograph", "La La", "Eldrick", "stars", "12", "dreamt", "Swiss Franc", "Samuel Beckett", "liquid assets", "Jupiter", "False, none do", "trumpet", "the fear of the number 13", "Sesame Street", "Icarus", "chloryphyll"];

function askQuestion() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var ask = prompt(questions[number]);

        if (ask === answers[number]) {

            score++;

            numofq++;

            alert("CORRECT! You have got " + score + " out of " + numofq + " questions correct so far.");

        } else {

            numofq++;

            alert("INCORRECT!You have got " + score + " out of " + numofq + " questions correct so far. The correct answer is " + answer[number]);

        } //End of for

        var percent = (score / numofq) * 100;

        if (numofq === 10) {

            alert("You got " + percent + "%");

        }

    } // End of function

}


askQuestion();
```

Comment: @BrantOlsen: If you're gonna fix a post, fix ___all___ the problems in it.

Comment: Do not use bold tags inside of code blocks

Comment: What is not working? Please give details? Any errors in the console?

Comment: You get this error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: answer is not defined`.  Try changing this line `alert("INCORRECT!You have got " + score + " out of " + numofq + " questions correct so far. The correct answer is " + answer[number]);` to `answers[number]`.

Comment: @JonathanDuffy adding as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: answer is not defined

Change this line:

```
alert("INCORRECT!You have got " + score + " out of " + numofq + 
" questions correct so far. The correct answer is " + answer[number]);
```

To have `answers`. Like this:

```
alert("INCORRECT!You have got " + score + " out of " + numofq + 
" questions correct so far. The correct answer is " + answers[number]);
```